# Unity doesn't show a problem, but still gets an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity and C#, and I tried to make a door that rotates -90 degrees around the Y when you enter a Trigger, but it doesn't work. it Shows no errors, bt when I try to play it, it says:
"All compiler errors need to be fixed before you can enter playmode."
I have no idea what is wrong, can you help me out?
This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorToggle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform movement;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerisoverlapping)
        {
            movement.transform.Rotation = Vector3(0f, -90f, 0f);
        }
        else
        {
            movement.transform.Rotation =Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerisoverlapping = true;
        }
    }

    void OntriggerExit (collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerisoverlapping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined `playerisoverlapping` and you're missing a semicolon after `movement.transform.Rotation =Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Community. The error message **"All compiler errors need to be fixed before you can enter playmode."** in Unity indicates that you have a syntax error in one of your scripts, so Unity can't compile your code.

In this instance you missed a semicolon at the end of:

**movement.transform.Rotation =Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)**

Comment: Thanks! You realyy helped me out